# where to put Entity Framework configuration strings in a WebAPI application

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, connection-string, configuration-files

I have started a WebAPI application using VS empty application template.
First, I have added the WebAPI service functionality - no issues.
Now, I need to add Entity Framework functionality, and I'm facing the following issue:
I do not have an App.config file in my application. Where can I put my database configuration parameters such as "Data Source=", "defaultConnectionFactory", etc...?
Currently, my ApplicationDbContext file looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebAPIService.Models
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DcToolDB")
        {

        }

        public IDbSet<Site> Sites { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Quote> Quotes { get; set; }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<ApplicationDbContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            base.Seed(context);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you do not have web.config?

Comment: I just realized - I do have an App.config file. Will see if I can specify everything correctly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give a more exact answer to this question: you have to include the configuration file (`app.config` or `web.config`) in the project that will be executed, and not in any other class library project. If the configuration file doesn't exist, create one. You can do it easily in VS by adding a new item of type "Configuration file" in the chosen project. It will create a `web.config` file or an `app.config` depending on the kind of project.

What does "the project that will be executed" mean?

When it's a desktop application or a web site, it's very clear. But, if you have a test project, that will be the executable project qhen you run the tests. So, if you have for example a web application with a two different test projects, you need 3 config files:

- `web.config` in the web app project, which sill be used when running the app
- one `app.config` for each test project, which will be used when you run the corresponding tests

This is interesting, beacuse it allows to keep different configurations for each project.

Answer (score 0):

I did have App.config after all, just did not see it at first.
Once located, I have added a section for Entity Framework:

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS2012; Initial Catalog=DcToolDB; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

and was able to accomplish the desired result.